# Powershell implicit remoting called from another module file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, remoting

We have a number of Powershell scripts that call "modules" with a load of reusable functions in. One function we have in a module sets up implicit remoting to our main DC and then imports the active directory module to the local session. I know this works as I have pasted the function into Powershell and it works. But when a script loads the module that contains the function it imports correctly but the cmdlets are not useable from the main script. I imagine this is something to do with scoping but I just can't see how to get this to work. For reference we cannout change the idea of calling modules with reusable functions in as there to many scripts that rely on it and it would be a big job to change it.

--Added for clarification from a comment below

I have a script, lets call it Script1, this script does some stuff but also loads some additional functions from other script modules using the following code

```
$Global:ICTSGVModuleLocation="\\server1\Scripts\Support Files\PS Modules\Global     Modules"
get-childitem $Script:ICTSGVModuleLocation | foreach-object $_.name {Import-Module "$Global:ICTSGVModuleLocation\$_" -Global}
```

In one of the other script modules (lets call it script2) is some code to create an implicit remoting session and import an active directory module, code below

```
Function Global:ICTSGF.Adconnecter
{Try {$Script:connect = new-pssession -ComputerName "$Global:ICTSGVAdConnectorServer";
invoke-command -session $script:connect {import-module activedirectory -prefix cardiff};
Import-Module (Import-PSSession -session $Script:connect -module ActiveDirectory -   AllowClobber) -Global}
Catch {ICTSGF.ScriptOutput "E2" "A4" "Loading Active Directory Module Failed"}
Finally {}}
```

In the main script (script1) i load the function by calling Global:ICTSGF.Adconnecter. This then loads the banner saying loading active Directory module and it appears to work. However when i attempt to run a command from the module imported it doesnt work

```
get-cardiffaduser $user
```

Thanks

Comment: So you have scripts loading modules, and you want the module's functions to be available at the interactive prompt? Are you using the `-Global` switch with the `Import-Module` command?

Comment: show us your code, or at least part of it

Comment: Yeah, kind of. I have scripts that call scripts, and they call an implicit remoting session to load an activedirectory module. And i want the main script to be able to see those called commands but currently they dont. I will edit the original post with the code i am using